# How to use setProjection correctly?

Tags: hibernate

I want to retrieve only certain columns in my UserAccount class so I have the code below:

```
UserAccount aUser = (UserAccount)currentSession().createCriteria(UserAccount.class)
                        /*  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                                    .add(Projections.property("id"))
                                    .add(Projections.property("username"))
                                    .add(Projections.property("email"))
                                    .add(Projections.property("displayname"))) */
                            .add(Restrictions.eq("email", email))
                            .add(Restrictions.eq("password", password))
                            .add(Restrictions.eq("enabled", true))
                            .add(Restrictions.eq("role", Role.CUSTOMER))
                            .uniqueResult();
    System.out.println(aUser);
    return aUser;
```

I got the null in return. But If I comment out the setProjections, I will get the user with all the properties. How can I use setProjection correctly in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns an Object array, so the code should be:

```
Object[] rows = (Object[]) session
        .createCriteria(UserAccount.class)
        .setProjection(
                Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.property("id"))
                        .add(Projections.property("username"))
                        .add(Projections.property("email"))
                        .add(Projections.property("displayname")))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("email", email))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("password", password))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("enabled", true))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("role", Role.CUSTOMER))
        .uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

With projections we should use **result transformer** and **aliasing**:

```
UserAccount aUser = (UserAccount)currentSession()
    // FROM
    .createCriteria(UserAccount.class)
    // WHERE
    .add(Restrictions.eq("email", email))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("password", password))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("enabled", true))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("role", Role.CUSTOMER))
    // SELECT with alias
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
       .add(Projections.property("id"),"id")             // alias is a must for
       .add(Projections.property("username"),"username") // result transformer
       .add(Projections.property("email"),"email")
       .add(Projections.property("displayname"),"displayname")
    )
    // here we go - this will convert projection into entity
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(UserAccount.class))
    .uniqueResult();
```

Check:

- [Complex Hibernate Projections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105757/)
- [B.9. Projections, aggregation and grouping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-projection)

Comment: Wow, I see, you prefer object[], weird... enjoy Hibernate anyhow ;)