# Hibernate Criteria Projection without mapped association of tables

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have 2 tables say

> Table1 and Table2
>
> Now Table1 has 3 columns say t1, t2, t3 and Table2 has 2 columns t4
>   and t5.

I have to fetch data from both tables by join but there is no mapped association between two tables in annotation or xml.

Now main issue is I have to use hibernate projection to fetch selected columns from both tables say t1,t2 from Table1 and t4 from Table2.

I have gone through the internet but have found examples of tables with association.

Glad if there will be any guidance on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this **is supported** in Hibernate. The only thing here is that we have to use **HQL**:

- [16.2. The from clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-from) *(cite:)*

> Multiple classes can appear, resulting in a cartesian product or "cross" join.

```
from Formula, Parameter
from Formula as form, Parameter as param
```

So in our case:

```
session
   .createQuery("SELECT t1.prop1, t1.prop2, t1.prop3 "
              + "       t2.prop4, t2.prop5 "
              + " FROM Entity1 AS t1, Entity2 As t2 " +
              // if there is some relation - unmapped
              + " WHERE t1.someProperty = t2.someProperty "
              + "   AND ... "
              )
   .setMaxResults(10) // we can even page here
   .list()
```

*NOTE: I used prop1, prop2 and Entity1, Entity2 ... to force the feeling that this is HQL. We are talking about mapped entities, not tables or columns*

And we will recieve collection of `object[]` array...

Comment: Thanks Radim but I am using Hibernate criteria and hibernate projection to achieve this and I don't have any mappings between the entities representing Table1 and Table2.

Comment: Once again ;) 1) This feature is supported only in HQL and 2) we do not have any relation between these tables! No. Check my HQL. it is just CROSS JOIN... and if you like... you can add WHERE... but you do not have to. It is **not** supported with Criteria. But if you will check that.. it is almost the same. As criteria and projection! Just pass result transformer.. SUMMARY: 1) with hql, 2) without any mapped relation and 3) with result [transformer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25616261/1679310) ... you can have your results. NOTE: only thing needed is that both tables are mapped as entities

Comment: Thanks Radim I guess I will use HQL to achieve the same.

Comment: Great sir! Enjoy awesome Hibernate ;)