# Hibernate get entity with specific columns of nested entity

Tags: hibernate, projection

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "animals")
public class Animal extends BaseEntity {
    private String nickname;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "species_id", nullable = false)
    private Species species;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "species")
public class Species extends BaseEntity {
    private String scientificName;
    private Integer animalsPerHouse;
}
```

How to get `Animal` with specific `Species` field, `scientificName` for example? How to tell to Hibernate that I need only specific fields of nested entity?

Desired animal:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nickname": "Locuroumee",
    "species": {
      "id": 161130,
      "scientificName": "Anguilla bicolor",
  }
```

Actual animal:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nickname": "Locuroumee",
    "species": {
      "id": 161130,
      "scientificName": "Anguilla bicolor",
      "animalsPerHouse": 4
  }
```

I already spent much time with projections, aliases, but it doesn't help

Comment: I have similar problem to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105757/complex-hibernate-projections)

Answer (score 0):

There are entity graphs for such tasks.

[Dynamic fetching via JPA entity graph](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching-entity-graph)

[JPA 2.1 Entity Graph – Part 1: Named entity graphs](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/)

[JPA 2.1 Entity Graph – Part 2: Define lazy/eager loading at runtime](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-2-define/)

But, looks like, Hibernate doesn't support  partial fields loading, opposite EclipseLink.

You can try to use a custom result transformer for it: 
[How to transform a flat result set using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36361630/3405171)

Comment: Projection serves to partial fields loading. And it works) And it may work with nested entity fields... but I don't know how

Comment: @hardcoder Please, see an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36361630/3405171

Comment: already saw) they use custom transformer. But apparently there are solution  without it.

Comment: @hardcoder Which the solution? Please, add it to the question. Without a transformer, using projections, you will have `List<Object[]>`.

Comment: I use **aliasToBean** transformer to avoid this. Maybe you know how to add projection to nested entity fields?

Comment: @hardcoder You can't use `aliasToBean` for nested fields. Please, see an example, as I have told you: there is the `createAlias()` method there, to add projections to the nested fields

Comment: Tried yours **FluentHibernateResultTransformer**  - is a solution)) Strangely, our teamlead hinted that custom transformer or projections are suitable for this problem

Comment: @hardcoder I am very glad to help you. I have some other interesting utilities classes, like a naming strategy. And I am going to extend `FluentHibernateResultTransformer` to support HQL nested projections.